# Passing two parameters to controller from a drop down list and javascript

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, linq, webgrid

I am creating an application in **c#** with **mvc 2010 Express** and I have one view made from 3 different tables: `tmarkets`, `tcountries` and `tanalysis`.
Each market has many countries and each country can have more than one analysis (defined by a `code`).

I have a view to select the analysis to consult (It passes the code to the controller) and then in the next view I have a **drop down list** of different markets (So that the user can see the analysis of the countries of that market for that analysis). 
I need to have **two different views** because I also need to have other options in the second one.

`Inform` Controller:

```
public ActionResult Filter(string id)
{
    var merc = from a in dre.v_AnalysisCountry
               where a.Code == id
               select a;
    var query1 = merc.Select (a => new { a.Code,a.Market}).Distinct().OrderBy(a => a.Market);
    ViewBag.mar = new SelectList(query1.AsEnumerable(), "Code", "Market");
    return View();
}
```

View `Filter`:

```cs
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $("#Market").change(function () {
    var actionUrl = $('#TheForm1').attr('action') + '/' + $('#Market').val();
        $('#TheForm1').attr('action', actionUrl);
        $('#TheForm1').submit();
    });
});
</script>

@using (Html.BeginForm("FilterAnMark", "Inform", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "TheForm1"})){
@Html.DropDownList("Market", (SelectList)ViewBag.mar, "Select a market")
```

}

In order to populate the drop down list with the different markets, my consult selects them from the `code` and the `market` itself so that later I can pass the code of the analysis to the controller for the next `view`.

The **problem** is that I would also need to pass the market to the `controller` and not only to the user in the *drop down list*. 
I tried to do something like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("FilterAnMark", "Inform", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "TheForm1", id2 = @ViewBag.idAn })){
    @Html.DropDownList("Market", (SelectList)ViewBag.mar, "Select a market")
}
```

and then in my `controller`:

```
var idAnalysis = (from v in dre.v_AnalysisCountry
                  where v.Code == id
                  select v.IdAnalysisCountry).FirstOrDefault();
ViewBag.idAn = idAnalysis;
```

But its not working.

----------------------------------------------------------*EDIT*------------------------------------------------------------------

I added a **hidden attribute** in my view:

```
@{
    string code= ViewBag.code;
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("FilterAnMark", "Inform", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "TheForm1"})){
    @Html.DropDownList("Market", (SelectList)ViewBag.mar, "Select a market")
    @Html.Hidden("code", code)
}
```

And it works, as it passes the code to the next view. 
The problem here comes in the next view. I am using a **WebGrid** to display the countries.

```
WebGrid grid = new WebGrid(Model, defaultSort: "Market", rowsPerPage: 15);
```

When the user tries to display the **second page** of the table, it displays a blank table, as it doesn't remember this hidden attribute.

I would be very grateful if you could help me with another solution or fixing this partial solution I found. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved the problem with the **hidden attribute** by adding one intermediate ActionResult (`IntermFilter`) in my Controller.

It receives the `Market` and the `Code` and obtains the Id of the first analysis that fulfills those two parameters. Then it redirects to a view in which the WebGrid is rendered as before, as in the `FilterMarket` ActionResult it obtains the `Market` and `Code` from the `IdAnalysis`.

Here is my code:

```cs
public ActionResult IntermFilter(string id, string code)
{
    int idFirstAn = (from m in dre.v_AnalysisCountry
                      where m.Code == code && m.Market == id
                      select m.IdAnalysis).FirstOrDefault();
    return RedirectToAction("FilterAnMark", new { id = idFirstAn });
}

public ActionResult FilterAnMark(int id)
{
    var query = (from m in dre.v_AnalysisCountry
                 where m.IdAnalysis == id
                 select m).FirstOrDefault();
    var countries = new FilterManager().ObtainMarkets(query.Code, query.Market);
    ViewBag.code = query.Code;
    ViewBag.market = query.Market;
    return View(countries);
}
```